# Rails 4.2 Scope queries IS NULL instead of IS NOT NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm literally just a few days old from learning Rails and I'm currently working on queries using scopes.

I have this simplified code:

```
Class Product  < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to: producer
   scope: get_items, => {where.not(producer{id: nil})}
```

Firing up `rails c` and typing in `Product.get_items` it instead produces:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (producer_id IS NULL)
```

when I needed:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (producer_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Did some research and also tried `{where("producer_id IS NOT NULL")}` but doesn't make the query different.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Product.where.not(producer_id: nil)` does it work?

Comment: Try this 

`scope :get_items, (lambda do
    where.not(producer_id: nil)
  end)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scope: where.not(producer{id: nil}` shouldn't work at all. Instead:

```
# if you need to filter by the attribute of the current model
scope :with_producer, -> { where.not(producer_id: nil) }

# if you need to filter by the attribute of the associated model
scope :with_named_producer, -> { joins(:producer).where.not(producers: { name: nil }) }
```